# minimal sufficient statistic

Tags: sufficient-statistics

Let X ~ Ber(n1; p), Y ~ Ber(n2; p^2), where X and Y are independent. Find a minimal
sufficient statistic T and, using a nontrivial function, show that it is not complete.

I get confused by having two different distribution! is it true to simply multiply these two distribution and use factorization theory?

Comment: I think so, because the joint density f(x,y|p)=f(x|p)f(y|p) because they are independent. But what is Bern(n1, p)? Bernoulli has just one parameter. Do you mean Binomial?

Comment: I double @Stacker, what do you mean by $Ber(n_1; p)$?

Comment: it seems that, it ends with two different variable that can not merge with each other in a good way !!

Comment: I am sorry but that does not answer the question of what do you mean by $Ber$?

Comment: @mrsergazinov, I am actually not sure but you are right, it should be Bin(n1,p) and Bin(n2,p^2), or just Be(p) and Be(p^2),  but I think it does not make much difference in solution path.

Comment: I think the easiest way here would be to use the Lehmann-Scheffe theorem to obtain your MSS.

Comment: so it means that I should find T and then use Lehmann-theorem, my question is when I use factorization theory, its end up with "p^sumX+2sumY . (1-p)^n1-sumX . (1-p^2)^n2-sumY"  . I dont know how to use factorization theory for this equation. @mrsergazinov

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119841/discussion-between-mrsergazinov-and-sara-st).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write the likelihood function: $$f(x,y|p) = [p^x(1-p)^{1-x}][p^{2y}(1-p^2)^{1-y}]$$
From this use the Lehmann-Scheffe Theorem. Need to find $T$ such that $$T(x_1, y_1) = T(x_2, y_2) \Leftrightarrow \frac{f(x_1,y_1|p)}{f(x_2,y_2|p)} = c(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)$$
To this end, let's compute the likelihood ratio:
\begin{align}
\frac{f(x_1,y_1|p)}{f(x_2,y_2|p)} &= 
\frac{p^{x_1}(1-p)^{1-x_1}p^{2y_1}(1-p^2)^{1-y_1}}{p^{x_2}(1-p)^{1-x_2}p^{2y_2}(1-p^2)^{1-y_2}} \\
&= p^{(x_1 - x_2)} (1-p)^{x_2 - x_1}p^{2(y_1 - y_2)} (1-p^2)^{y_2-y_1}
\end{align}
It can be seen then that the ratio does not depend on $p$ if and only if $x_1 = x_2, y_1 = y_2$. By the Lehmann-Scheffe, this implies that $T(X, Y) = (X, Y)$ is the minimal sufficient statistic.

Comment: do you know,how I can show that this is not complete??! because it seems that is complete but in the question ask to show that its not complete!

Comment: I have not worked this out, but you can try and find some function $g$ of $T(X, Y) = (X, Y)$ that has $E_p[g(X, Y)] = 0$ for all $p$ with $g$ not being $=0$ almost everywhere.